# Display content type through custom template

Tags: theming, hooks, nodes

I have been losing quite a lot of time with something that seemed straightforward initially.

I am trying to use a template file(tpl.php) to print a content type with custom html layout.

In template.php I added.

```
function responsive_bartik_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
  if ($variables['type'] == 'dagens_billet') {
    $variables['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'templates/dagens_billet--template';
   }
}
```

I added a templates/dagens_billet--template.tpl.php but nothing is being printed.
I've added the following test code in there:

```
<?php print render('Giannisssssssssssssss'); ?>
```

Any suggestions to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is my method for doing such thing and it always works.

create a view of your content type (`ct`), say `ct__view`. create a page and rename it to
 `page--path_of_view.tpl.php` and embed that view inside it at any where you want with this instruction `<?php print views_embed_view('ct__view','page');?>`. now you can customize its fields output with `views-view-fields--ct__view--page.tpl.php`

Comment: Where do you place all these files?

Comment: at your theme folder for me on localhost is `C:\xampp\htdocs\MY_THEME_NAME\sites\all\themes\MY_THEME_NAME`

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found is quite simple. 
Just creating a sites/all/themes/{mytheme}/templates/node-{content_type_machine_name}.tpl.php

This is explained nicely at http://www.slideshare.net/aimeemaree/a-look-at-drupal-7-theming

Comment: this method `node--ct.tpl.php` does not  work on drupal 7 any more.